# Can moderated comments be recovered?

Tags: support, comments

I remember some of the comments following post [How can I sort the lines in this text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/758758/how-can-i-sort-the-lines-in-this-text-file) seem helpful about usage of `sort` and about sorting algorithm. Now they are gone. Can they be recovered? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There really wasn't much that seems particularly useful, but here's a screenshot of the possibly relevant deleted comments:

[image: screenshot of deleted comments]